# Library does not have JAVADOC code complete assistance

Tags: java, ant, proguard, code-completion

I wrote my own android library. To test it, I wrote a tester application, added the JAR to it and also added it to the build path (in Eclipse).

Eclipse's auto completion shows the (public) API methods (which is good) but the following are missing:

- The Javadoc description of the methods.
- The method parameter names

  ```
  MyLibrary.myapimethod(String arg0, String arg1)
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  MyLibrary.myapimethod(String param, String anotherparam)
  ```

The code is built using ant and obfuscated using Proguard.

How do I make sure that code-completion of my library's parameter names and documentation are available to users (e.g. the tester app)?

Comment: Eclipse, and many other IDEs, expect a separate Javadoc source, and/or source code JAR, to make this work. The best you can do is distribute your Javadocs (in JAR form if necessary) and source code, as three separate JARs (Library + source + javadoc), and the users will have to configure their IDE accordingly (e.g. attaching source and javadoc to build path libraries in eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

To keep method parametres names include `-keepparameternames` in proguard rules file (proguard-rules.pro)